# Salesforce form showing errors even when filled out correctly

Tags: javascript, html, forms, salesforce

I am new to salesforce and don't have a lot of experience with javascript. The issue I am having is that as I am testing a form and filling out the inputs it is adding the the "has-error" class to the parent div even when the input is filled out correctly. However, it will allow the form to be submitted so it is not conflicting with that.

I took over the work from another developer so Im not sure what is causing the error.

The is the javascript for the salesforce form. I am also using validate.js:

```
'use strict';

var constraints = {
    // First Name
    '00N4100000CJ8sT': {
        presence: {
            message: '^First Name is required'
        },
        length: {
            maximum: 80
        }
    },
    // Last Name
    '00N4100000CJ8sY': {
        presence: {
            message: '^Last Name is required'
        },
        length: {
            maximum: 80
        }
    },
    // Appointment Date
    '00N4100000EWaN0': {
        presence: {
            message: '^Date is not valid'
        },
        format: {
            pattern: /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/,
        },
    },
    // Patient Email
    '00N4100000CJ8sE': {
        presence: {
            message: '^Email is required'
        },
        email: {
            message: '^Email is not valid'
        }
    },
    // Phone
    'phone': {
        presence: true,
        format: {
            pattern: /^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$/,
            message: '^Phone Number is not valid'
        }
    }
};

$('.salesforce-form').each(function () {

    var form = this;
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        handleFormSubmit(form);
    });

    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea, select');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
        inputs.item(i).addEventListener('change', function (ev) {
            var errors = validate(form, constraints) || {};
            showErrorsForInput(this, errors[this.name]);
        });
    }

    function handleFormSubmit(form, input) {
        var errors = validate(form, constraints);
        showErrors(form, errors || {});
        if (!errors) {
            showSuccess(form);
        }
    }

    function showErrors(form, errors) {
        _.each(form.querySelectorAll('input[name], select[name]'), function (input) {
            showErrorsForInput(input, errors && errors[input.name]);
        });
    }

    function showErrorsForInput(input, errors) {
        var formGroup = closestParent(input, 'form-group');
        var messages = formGroup.querySelector('.messages');
        resetFormGroup(formGroup);
        if (errors) {
            formGroup.classList.add('has-error');
            _.each(errors, function (error) {
                addError(messages, error);
            });
        } else {
            formGroup.classList.add('has-success');
        }
    }

    function closestParent(child, className) {
        if (!child || child == document) {
            return null;
        }
        if (child.classList.contains(className)) {
            return child;
        } else {
            return closestParent(child.parentNode, className);
        }
    }

    function resetFormGroup(formGroup) {
        formGroup.classList.remove('has-error');
        formGroup.classList.remove('has-success');
        _.each(formGroup.querySelectorAll('.help-block.error'), function (el) {
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        });
    }

    function addError(messages, error) {
        var block = document.createElement('p');
        block.classList.add('help-block');
        block.classList.add('error');
        block.innerText = error;
        messages.appendChild(block);
    }

    function showSuccess(form) {
        var myEmail = form.querySelector('#my-email').value;

        if (!myEmail.length > 0) {
            form.querySelector('#orgid').value = '00D41000000MWct';
            var postData = $(form).serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '(salesforce url goes here)',
                data: postData,
                success: function success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    //data: return data from server
                },
                error: function error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //if fails
                    $(form).find('.form-group').fadeOut();
                    $('.thank-you-message').last().clone().appendTo(form).fadeIn();
                    dataLayer.push({
                        'event': 'gtm.formSubmit',
                        'gtm.elementClasses': form.className
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This is the html for the salesforce form:

```
<form class="salesforce-form salesforce-contact-form" novalidate>
    <div class="hide form-group">
        <input id="my-email" name="my-email" type="text" />
        <input type="hidden" id="orgid" name="orgid" />

        <input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" value="test@email.com"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="00N4100000IkI2v" name="00N4100000IkI2v" value="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" id="00N4100000IkHtO" name="00N4100000IkHtO" value="<?php echo get_client_ip(); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" id="00N4100000HxXj4" name="00N4100000HxXj4" value="New" />
        <input type="hidden" id="00N4100000CL2tK" name="00N4100000CL2tK" value="Request Appointment" title="Form Type" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group first-name">
        <label for="00N4100000CJ8sT" class="hidden">First Name</label>
        <input id="00N4100000CJ8sT" maxlength="80" name="00N4100000CJ8sT" size="20" type="text" placeholder="First Name: *">
        <div class="messages"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group last-name">
        <label for="00N4100000CJ8sY" class="hidden">Last Name</label>
        <input id="00N4100000CJ8sY" maxlength="80" name="00N4100000CJ8sY" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Last Name: *">
        <div class="messages"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group email">
        <label for="00N4100000CJ8sE" class="hidden">Email</label>
        <input id="00N4100000CJ8sE" maxlength="80" name="00N4100000CJ8sE" size="20" type="email" placeholder="Email: *">
        <div class="messages"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group phone">
        <label for="phone" class="hidden">Phone</label>
        <input id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Phone: *">
        <div class="messages"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 form-group appointment-date">
        <label for="00N4100000EWaN0" class="hidden">Appointment Date</label>
        <input id="00N4100000EWaN0" name="00N4100000EWaN0" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Appointment Date: *">
        <div class="messages"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group comments">
        <label for="description" class="hidden">Comments</label>
        <textarea id="description" name="description" placeholder="Comments:"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit +" class="btn small"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Let me know if this needs more explanation or if you need to see any other files.

Comment: Are you getting any js console errors?  I was going to transform your question's code into a runnable snippet, but when I included all the libraries it seemed to work ok (ie, no error message was appearing for elements correctly filled out).  [Here's a fiddle of "working" code](https://jsfiddle.net/ege4zhs8/)

Comment: Nope I get no console errors. Could it be because I have more than one form on a page?

Comment: It might be.  For example you assign event listeners to all input, textarea, select even though they might not be on the same .salesforce-form (try changing document.querySelectorAll to form.querySelectorAll).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! It worked!